# The importance of a name with meaning

Tags: names, commentaries, pregnancy-birth

**What is the importance of a name?**

I read this on the Aish website:[link](http://www.aish.com/jl/l/b/48961326.html)

> The naming of a Jewish child is a most profound spiritual moment. The
>   Sages say that naming a baby is a statement of her character, her
>   specialness, and her path in life. For at the beginning of life we
>   give a name, and at the end of life a "good name" is all we take with
>   us. (see Talmud – Brachot 7b; Arizal – Sha'ar HaGilgulim 24b)

Now i wondered if there are more reverences to the importance of giving/having a proper, fitting, good name?

Comment: I don't understand what you seek. What's a "reverence" in this context?